# Bottom navigation bar to magnify selected item

Tags: android, android-bottomnav

I want to create a bottom navigation bar in my Android project. Here are 5 items(just items icons. No name of any item) in the navigation bar. I want to make it in a way so that when an item is selected it is magnified a little along with showing its name.
How can I do this?

P.S. - I instead tried with an imageview inside of which there are imagebuttons. One non-magnified icon imagebutton and the corresponding magnified icon (+ its name) imagebutton are overlapped, setting one visible and other invisible alternatively, but it was a bad idea. The code works but the layout is very bad and messy.

Comment: You must be using the older version of the 'com.android.support:design' and if you are using the newer version then its automatically done as per my belief. Try using: implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer with Tip:**

***Answer:***

That's the default behavior if you use the latest `support:design` library and then implement your `BottomNavigationView`. As stated in my comment above; below your question.

**Some links to implement Bottom Navigation View (which you would have easily got if you would have googled for them):**

**1]**  [How to Code a Bottom Navigation Bar for an Android App](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-code-a-bottom-navigation-bar-for-an-android-app--cms-30305)

**2]**  [Android Working with Bottom Navigation](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/)

***Tip:***

But the problem with the knowledge gained from the above links is; *Material Design documentation* tells us that if the Bottom Navigation has:

**3 items — we should display the icon with text (always) for all items.**

**4–5 items — we should display text for active icon only and hide for inactive items (or views).**

[image]

Now, you might have a good guess on what I’m going to say next.

*“This is what the Material Design guidelines suggest, so let’s just do this.”*

But this time I won’t. I disagree, and so should you. I’ll tell you why.

**The Material Design guidelines aren’t always right.**

> Whether you have 3 or 5 items in your Bottom Navigation, **ALWAYS** show
>   text labels!

By doing so, you’ll avoid the [Mystery Meat Navigation problem that plagues Material Design](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/material-design-and-the-mystery-meat-navigation-problem-65425fb5b52e). Shoutout to [Teo Yu Siang](https://medium.com/@teoyusiang) for making aware of this!

> **Buttons or links that don’t explain to you what they do. Instead, you
>   have to click on them to find out — Mystery Meat Navigation.**

I’m sure we’ve all been victims of this at some point at least. We click on a button assuming it to do something, only for it to do something else entirely!

So do yourselves, and your users a favor. Always, show text labels for your Bottom Navigation icons.

By mentioning this (for instance): `bottomNavigation.setTitleState(AHBottomNavigation.TitleState.ALWAYS_SHOW);`

**I did my part to give good UX. Rest all depends on you.**

**Tip -- Source and Credit:** [Ultimate Guide to Bottom Navigation on Android](https://android.jlelse.eu/ultimate-guide-to-bottom-navigation-on-android-75e4efb8105f)

Answer (score 2):

You can use BottomNavigationView from android support library.

Use the following dependency-

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
```

And use following in the xml file for bottom navigation bar-

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

**Note** - For the magnifying behaviour to work, you need to have more than 3 items in your BottomNavigationView.